# cant set php key-value pair set properly

Tags: php, object, keyvaluepair

I have a key value pair that I am using inside of a class, but it is not returning the data the way I want it.  I want the value in GB&Lv to be in the key area and the value to be in the value area.  However my debug output seems to indicate that I am currently placing the value in the key section of the key value pair?

```
class Player{
    var $PlayerName ;
    var $TotalContributedPoints;
    function GetTotalContributedPoints()
    {
            $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "foe_gb_contribs_test");
        if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
           echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        }

        $debug = true;

        if ($debug == true) {echo $this->PlayerName.'<br>';}
        $QuerySQL = "SELECT * FROM `GB_Contribs` WHERE Player_Nick = '".$this->PlayerName."' order by DATE ASC";
        if ($debug == true) {echo 'Query is '.$QuerySQL.'<br>';}
        $ContribArray = array("Key" => "Value");
        $result = $mysqli->query($QuerySQL);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $ContribArray[$row['GB&Lv']] = $row['Value'];
            }
            foreach($ContribArray as $key => $value) {
                echo "Player_nick: ". $this->PlayerName ."<br>";
                echo "Great Building Level: ".$ContribArray[$key]."<br>";
                echo "Contribution Points".$ContribArray[$value]."<br>";
            }
            return $ContribArray;

        }  else {
            if ($debug == true) {echo "0 results";}
            return;
        }


    }

}// END of Player Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're iterating the array with foreach, you already have the key and value. You don't need to refer to the array again.

```
foreach($ContribArray as $key => $value) {
    echo "Player_nick: ". $this->PlayerName ."<br>";
    echo "Great Building Level: ".$key."<br>";         // not $ContribArray[$key]
    echo "Contribution Points".$value."<br>";          // not $ContribArray[$value]
}
```

As it is, `$ContribArray[$key]` gets you the value, and I would assume `$ContribArray[$value]` doesn't get you anything. In fact, it seems like it would probably cause an undefined index notice.

Comment: The overall plan is for the object to be self contained and pass the key value par back as a result of the function.  That section of the code will be in a 

    if ($debug == true) {} 

section when done.  But right now the problem is that the

    echo "Great Building Level: ".$key."<br>";

line is returning the value I want to show up in the 
    echo "Contribution Points".$value."<br>";
line.  That indicates to me that I am loading the array incorrectly from what I want.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is, `$ContribArray` is probably fine, but that foreach output just makes it look like it isn't.

Comment: @CoderWolf Your code does not have a `"Great Building Level: ".$key."<br>";` line, it has a `"Great Building Level: ".$ContribArray[$key]."<br>";` line, which is quite different. If you are saying that you tried Don't Panic's solution and it also didn't work, then ignore this. But Don't Panic's point is valid given your original code.

Comment: Thanks, that is a little different pardigm than I was thinking from the foreach and explains an issue I was having when I took the $key=>$value out of the foreach.  I did not realize the look itself was assigning it to its own variable.  hense I did not realize those variable were there for me to use.

Comment: @PatrickQ Thanks, I tried to make that more evident by adding the comments in the code - maybe too subtle, though.

Comment: @PatrickQ you are correct.  I had not tried it.  When I saw the changes I tried it and realized the paradigm change.